# How to recover an office 2013 document, in windows 7, after removing the removable disk?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, data-recovery, file-recovery, microsoft-office-2013

There exist lots of information about data recovery in WWW as well as this question answering website, almost all of which about the situation in which you have the hard dist in your hand.

However, suppose that you have a removable disk and you always store your data on that (you use the removable disk as your hard disk). Suppose that you loose your access to the removable disk. How can you recover your (Microsoft office) document which was being opened, day by day, in your computer. Is there anywhere (e.g. Windows temp, Office temp) in which an archived copy of the files is stored?

Note: Suppose that you have searched for all `*.asd` files in your computer and could not find your lost files, after opening them all.

Answer (score 2):

NO,

there isn't anywhere else!

unless you saved it somewhere else (hard disk, cloud based storage ,etc)

Answer (score 0):

With default settings, Office autosaves unsaved documents at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles`. Those files are kept for four days. You might find some versions there.

If you haven't used your computer a lot after you lost your file, you can try forensic approaches to recover deleted files. Even if your file was stored on a removable drive, (temporary) copies may have existed on your hard drive. Look for "file carving".